# How to read text file into matrix in Python?

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python.
I have a text file like following:

```
"0","0","0","0","1","0"    
"0","0","0","2","1","0"
...
```

I want to import this text file as a matrix in Python.
I can find examples similar to this, but they don't have quotation marks for each value so it doesn't work directly for this case. How I can read only numerical values from text and save it as a matrix?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read the file and cast each value to `int` while you're reading the rows. You could possibly just split each row on commas and cast to int, but if it's a CSV, you might as well use the built-in library.

Answer (score 1):

A go to method for reading things into a list is the readlines() method for files. 
However, your data is a bit tricky since you have quotation marks. Note, these are not the usual quotation marks around a string declaration, but actual text.

We iterate through the values and remove them, then convert the remaining string to integer. We then append each row to a matrix:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines() # read raw lines into an array

cleaned_matrix = [] 
for raw_line in data:
    split_line = raw_line.strip().split(",") # ["1", "0" ... ]
    nums_ls = [int(x.replace('"', '')) for x in split_line] # get rid of the quotation marks and convert to int
    cleaned_matrix.append(nums_ls)

print cleaned_matrix
```

output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]]
```